Initilialize a typedef eigen vector from std::vector
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> EigenVectorX;
std::vector<double> v;
v.push_back(22);
v.push_back(55);
v.push_back(77);

EigenVectorX ev;

How I can initialize ev with v ?

See also here for more comments on copy vs. reference: Convert std::vector<double> to Eigen::ArrayXd in c++?

You can use Eigen::Map for this
EigenVectorX ev = Eigen::Map<EigenVectorX>(v.data(), v.size());


sorry for the edit, didn't see OP's typedef
